# Select control in Schema-Form gives wrong validation message

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

i have a form that uses Schema-Form, the form has "select" control.

When i am choosing value from the select, validation error appears: `Invalid type, expected string`- i don't know why..
[image]

When i inspect the element, using `Google chrome debugger`
[image]

```
vm.schema = {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            ...
            RelationType: { type: 'string', title: 'This Card' }
        }
 }


vm.form = [{
       key: 'RelationType',
            type: 'select',
            titleMap: JSON.parse(typeList)
        }]
```

What am i doing wrong here? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The value for each item in the titleMap is returning as a number, but your schema is set to hold a string. Either ensure the value in the titleMap is a string or change the type in the schema to number.

If you are holding numbers in strings you will find they are being parsed to numbers. Changing the schema to `[ "number", "string" ]` should do the trick but you may need to convert them going into your data store depending on your requirements.